# Set Eclipse not to insert blank lines between methods declaration in interfaces?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, settings, code-formatting

I'm having trouble to set up formatter not to insert blank lines between methods in interfaces. In the same time I still want to have blank lines between methods in classes. I cannot find appropriate formatter setting that would allow this. Can somebody point me to the right option?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The eclipse formatter doesn't check if your method is inside a class or an interface.

Comment: I agree with @vainolo. Went through the options and it doesn't seem like its possible to fine tune this separately for interfaces/regular classes.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in comments by vainolo, there isn't any direct option to do so. Following is the screenshot for the eclipse formatter for adding new lines and it doesn't distinguish between the methods of class and interface 
[image: eclipse formatter- black lines]

### Workaround

But, a simple manual work-around is possible. Select the lines as shown below, and run a simple `regex` **^\s*\n** find and replace to remove the blank lines.

[image: work around]

Hope this helps.